# Question about number of Google SQL query parameters (BigQuery)

Tags: google-bigquery

I am constructing a BigQuery query with 2 query parameters, for example, `@users` and `@appliances` where I put 14000 values to the `@users` and 2 values to `@appliances`

I found that not ALL of my 14000 users got updates by the query.
I suspect it is because BigQuery has this limit. Interestingly, there are no errors returned about the limit having been reached.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas
[image]

So is this correct that Google only allows a maximum 10,000 values to a query parameter in a query? (so I can put 10,000 values to @users and 10,000 values to @appliances)

or all query parameters in a query? (so I can put 9,999 values to @users and 1 value to @appliances)

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Khoi Vu, yes according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) a GoogleSQL query can have up to 10,000 parameters i.e according to your use case you

can put 10,000 values to users query and 10,000 values to appliances query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) a GoogleSQL query can have up to 10,000 parameters i.e according to your use case you  can put 10,000 values to users query and 10,000 values to appliances query.